# Pass flags to ignore cross origin issue on codeceptjs

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, codeceptjs

After chrome update all browser security my codeceptjs not working,
I need to pass this flags in order that iw will work.
I tried this but still have same issue

```
  desiredCapabilities: {
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--disable-web-security", '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--enable-experimental-cookie-features', '--allow-insecure-localhost', '--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt']
    }
  }
```

how can I pass this flags as picture here
The flags that should solve the problem are:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered correctly configuring CORS, instead?

Comment: this isn't an option for now